# Is there a way to see if there's data in any array elements with a named key without looping through the whole array?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm developing an application in PHP 7 which has a list of users and their dietary requirements.

**If any** of the users have dietary requirements I need to show a link to a page that can display them; conversley if **none** of the users have such requirements then this isn't shown.

My `$users` array looks like this:

```
[
    [ 'name' => 'Andy', 'diet' => '' ],
    [ 'name' => 'Bob', 'diet' => 'Vegeterian' ],
    [ 'name' => 'John', 'diet' => '' ]
]
```

So in the above example, Bob has dietary requirements and the button needs to be shown.

My plan to determine whether or not to show the button involves looping through the whole `$users` array, and if it finds any `'diet'` array elements which aren't empty, it shows the button, e.g.

```
$show_dietary_button = false;
foreach ($users as $user) {
    if ($user['diet'] !== '') {
       $show_dietary_button = true;
       break;
    }
}

if ($show_dietary_button) {
    echo '<a href="#">Show Dietary Requirements</a>';
}
```

Is there an easier way to do this, i.e. a way to say *do any of the array elements with a key 'diet' have data in them?*

Comment: your code doesn't iterate the whole array. You already stop the loop when you find a not-empty `diet` element.

Comment: @Federkun that's exactly what I want it to do. The button needs to be shown if 1 or more users have dietary requirements, i.e. if it finds only 1 person, that's enough for us to know we need the button.

Comment: then your code should works just fine.

Comment: @Federkun the code I've written works, the question is more to do with whether there's a more concise/efficient way of doing it. Thanks though.

Comment: `$show_dietary_button = count(array_filter(array_column($users, 'diet'))) > 0` is more concise but less efficient.

Comment: @Andy Please not that the answer which you accepted still loops the array within the function call so performance-wise it should be the same as your original solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just use a combination of `array_filter` and `array_column` to extract the column you want, then check if it's empty...

```
if (!empty(array_filter(array_column($records, 'diet')))) {
    $show_dietary_button = true;
}
```

Alternatively:

```
$show_dietary_button = !empty(array_filter(array_column($records, 'diet')));
```

Comment: you mean something like `if (count(array_filter(array_column($records, 'diet')))) {` ? `array_column` returns an array of values.

Comment: You can just assign the `if` expression to `$show_dietary_button`, that way you cover the `false` initialisation as well.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus fixed!